# reCaptcha Setup - White Screen After Correct Captcha Entered

Tags: php, captcha

I've recently setup reCaptcha and eveything works fine, but when I input the correct captcha all I get is a white screen - I know why this is it's because I'm supposed to tell reCaptcha where to go.

I just don't know PHP very well and don't know what to put, can anybody help me please, the php code is:

```
<?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                             $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                             $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                             $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
 // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
 die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
    "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put what happen in the `else` statement.

```
 } else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
 }
```